# Having trouble understanding(The proof of); $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ is finite implies the limit point set of $A$ is empty.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I am self-studying Complex Analysis. The idea behind the proof is clear, and I understand the intuition etc. There are a few statements that are really giving me trouble accepting this proof though. I also understand there are many ways of showing this result, but I would like to see it this way.

Definition of Limit Point:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be given. $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$ if for all $\epsilon >0, (D_\epsilon(\alpha) / \{\alpha\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset $ and we can denote the set of limit points by $A'$.

Here is the proof in question.

First, let $z \in \mathbb{C}/A$ be given. Then since this set is open, there exists $r  > 0$ such that $D_r(\color{red}\alpha) \subset \mathbb{C} / A$. In particular, $D'_r(\alpha) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

*Where am I taking $\alpha$?, is it implied that I am meant to take it in $\mathbb{C}$ from the definition?*

Now let $z \in A$ be given. Since $\mathbb{C}/(A/\{x \})$ is open and contains $z$, there exists an $r > 0$ such that $\color{red}{D_r(\alpha) \cap (A/\{z \})} = \emptyset$ and thus $$\color{red}{D'_r(\alpha) \cap A} = \emptyset$$

*I have taken $D'$ to mean the punctured disk/ball, now them red statements only make sense to me if $\alpha = z$*

I am not studying Topology.

Comment: There are, indeed, many typos in this: every $z$ should be $\alpha$ (or vice versa), and so should $x$. Also, $/$ should be $\setminus$ (or perhaps $-$). Also, $D'$ is a bad notation for the punctured disk since $A'$ is being defined for something else (and I'm not a great fan of $D_r(\alpha)$ in the first place, but that's beside the point).

Comment: I have copied it down exactly as well. Jesus. Thanks Gro-Tsen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$; we want to show $\alpha$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Since $A$ is finite, you can consider
$$
\varepsilon=\min\{|\alpha-x|:x\in A, x\ne\alpha\}
$$
Then $D_\varepsilon(\alpha)\cap A\subseteq\{\alpha\}$. Indeed, if $x\in D_\varepsilon(\alpha)\cap A$, then $|\alpha-x|<\varepsilon$, so the only possibility is $x=\alpha$.

(Note that if $\alpha\notin A$, the intersection is empty, but this is irrelevant.)

So $D_\varepsilon(\alpha)$ doesn't contain points of $A$ distinct from $\alpha$ and we have proved $\alpha$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: That's a far nicer version! thanks!

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Actually there's a minor error in the argument, because it is assumed that $A\ne\emptyset$; on the other hand, the case $A=\emptyset$ is quite easy.

Comment: Indeed we can take any $\epsilon > 0, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ then the intersection of the punctured disk with center $\alpha$ and radius $\epsilon$ with $A$ will be empty. Thanks, I would have forgotten that case to be honest egreg haha.